# Hash for an authorize-enact runtime upgrade?

Tags: runtime, upgrade, hash

Attempting a parachain runtime upgrade using `.runtimes.compact.subwasm.parachain_authorize_upgrade_hash` and `.runtimes.compact.wasm` from the `srtool-cli@v0.8.0` output. Enacting the runtime upgrade ends up with a hash mismatch failure. Also tried upgrading by authorizing the reported `.runtimes.compact.blake2_256` hash - which fails likewise.

```
{
  "gen": "srtool v0.9.20",
  "src": "git",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.0",
  "commit": "0a70aed7fc824ae51be4ec6b0940622673b6a3b5",
  "tag": "v0.0.0-up",
  "branch": "HEAD",
  "rustc": "rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)",
  "pkg": "my-parachain-runtime",
  "tmsp": "2022-06-29T10:36:15Z",
  "size": "4946919",
  "prop": "0x7ccbcd15bf46c21ef2dc18b3a23a32352deb9a439d0d6b15df1627871ad1b7bd",
  "ipfs": "QmRRuNCcy4eFUm1ZP8kcNALy89TAs1tSSeGN7kRVrM9tV6",
  "sha256": "0xbe06c07e6b4f2b9bbaff07263aac89df75559bf03863fea81f5ec9b09e0f9bd0",
  "wasm": "runtime/parachain/target/srtool/release/wbuild/my-parachain-runtime/my_parachain_runtime.compact.wasm",
  "info": {
    "generator": {
      "name": "srtool",
      "version": "0.9.20"
    },
    "src": "git",
    "version": "1.0.0-alpha.0",
    "git": {
      "commit": "0a70aed7fc824ae51be4ec6b0940622673b6a3b5",
      "tag": "v0.0.0-up",
      "branch": "HEAD"
    },
    "rustc": "rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)",
    "pkg": "my-parachain-runtime",
    "profile": "release"
  },
  "context": {
    "package": "my-parachain-runtime",
    "runtime_dir": "runtime/parachain",
    "docker": {
      "image": "paritytech/srtool",
      "tag": "1.60.0"
    },
    "profile": "release"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "compact": {
      "tmsp": "2022-06-29T10:35:56Z",
      "size": "4946919",
      "prop": "0x7ccbcd15bf46c21ef2dc18b3a23a32352deb9a439d0d6b15df1627871ad1b7bd",
      "blake2_256": "0x464d4f048640d36ab574880825856af908da5e5240e07970f00cb47a4fa60f28",
      "ipfs": "QmRRuNCcy4eFUm1ZP8kcNALy89TAs1tSSeGN7kRVrM9tV6",
      "sha256": "0xbe06c07e6b4f2b9bbaff07263aac89df75559bf03863fea81f5ec9b09e0f9bd0",
      "wasm": "runtime/parachain/target/srtool/release/wbuild/my-parachain-runtime/my_parachain_runtime.compact.wasm",
      "subwasm": {
        "size": 4946919,
        "compression": {
          "size_compressed": 4946919,
          "size_decompressed": 4946919,
          "compressed": false
        },
        "reserved_meta": [
          109,
          101,
          116,
          97
        ],
        "reserved_meta_valid": true,
        "metadata_version": 14,
        "core_version": "mine-2 (my Collator-1.tx2.au2)",
        "proposal_hash": "0x7ccbcd15bf46c21ef2dc18b3a23a32352deb9a439d0d6b15df1627871ad1b7bd",
        "parachain_authorize_upgrade_hash": "0x45d68032a4d5d2fbaa0e6b0a805c3103a9e5e48f03de718ad24336a99c606806",
        "ipfs_hash": "QmRRuNCcy4eFUm1ZP8kcNALy89TAs1tSSeGN7kRVrM9tV6",
        "blake2_256": "0x464d4f048640d36ab574880825856af908da5e5240e07970f00cb47a4fa60f28"
      }
    },
    "compressed": {
      "tmsp": "2022-06-29T10:35:56Z",
      "size": "976120",
      "prop": "0x1a3931ac4c740c832ee740930e13681f455584b4c9a159fd4e6b54d89cad0f96",
      "blake2_256": "0xddaa8de7a96ff6bf36d6f242a6c51379f1f00a760dfcc196404404ca34af291d",
      "ipfs": "QmYKbUqfcBa3sUGQpyjKYtaLf9UcMvJxuragr77gSfyxvr",
      "sha256": "0x9963e39718523b72cb605249051abf0443024b97d1928895eb9ccd121b008e79",
      "wasm": "runtime/parachain/target/srtool/release/wbuild/my-parachain-runtime/my_parachain_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm",
      "subwasm": {
        "size": 976120,
        "compression": {
          "size_compressed": 976120,
          "size_decompressed": 4946919,
          "compressed": true
        },
        "reserved_meta": [
          109,
          101,
          116,
          97
        ],
        "reserved_meta_valid": true,
        "metadata_version": 14,
        "core_version": "mine-2 (my Collator-1.tx2.au2)",
        "proposal_hash": "0x1a3931ac4c740c832ee740930e13681f455584b4c9a159fd4e6b54d89cad0f96",
        "parachain_authorize_upgrade_hash": "0xd50130eabfce85fd030268649f548d03e2e58be73ee758a93173930d8841266d",
        "ipfs_hash": "QmYKbUqfcBa3sUGQpyjKYtaLf9UcMvJxuragr77gSfyxvr",
        "blake2_256": "0xddaa8de7a96ff6bf36d6f242a6c51379f1f00a760dfcc196404404ca34af291d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell where the `0xb1cb...` hash came from. You need to use the compressed Wasm and the Blake2 hash.

Try doing the authorize with `"blake2_256": "0xddaa8de7a96ff6bf36d6f242a6c51379f1f00a760dfcc196404404ca34af291d"` and then submit the `<filename>.compact.compressed.wasm` file at the enact stage.